# Java - write obenglobish method

Tags: java

I have problem writing some method ... so if some1 can help, i would really appreciate it. Thank you.

**Task:**
- read word
- turn it in "obenglobish" - that means that you must add "OB" before vowel ...
for example: english will become --> OBenglOBish ...
**exception**: two vowel in the row && -e is the last char in the word.

This is what i wrote, no matter on exceptions:

```
    import acm.program.*;

public class ObenGlobishX extends ConsoleProgram {
    public void run() {
        println("OBENGLOBISH");
        while (true) {
            String word = readLine("Enter a word: ");
            if (word.equals("")) break;
            println(word + " --> " + obenglobish(word));
        }
    }

    private String obenglobish (String word) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            char c = word.charAt(i);
            if (isEnglishVowel(c)) result = result + "ob" + c;
            else result += c;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private boolean isEnglishVowel(char x) {
        if (x == 'a' || x == 'e' || x == 'i' || x == 'o' || x == 'u') return true;
        return false;
    }

}
```

It works for word like English and Rot (robot), but for word gooiest it doesn't work - two oo's ... need to find out how to modify method to get correct results ... that means:
gooiest -> gobooiest
amaze -> obamobaze 
etc.

THX

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: no... i'm learning java (beginner).. this is exercise in book The art and science of Java - Eric Roberts .. and i can't figure it out ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private String obenglobish (String word) {
    String result = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
        char c = word.charAt(i);
        if (isEnglishVowel(c)) {
            if (c == 'e' && i == word.length()-1) {
                result += c;
            } else {
                if(i!=0 && isEnglishVowel(word.charAt(i-1))) {
                    result += c;
                } else {
                    result = result + "ob" + c;
                }                   
            }
        } else {
            result += c;
        } 
    }
    return result;
}
```